# Partitioning data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
class Question:
    
    def __init__(self, column, value):
        self.column = column #storing a column number
        self.value = value #storing a column value
        
    def match(self,example):
       
        
        val = example[self.column]
        if is_numeric(val):
            return val >= self.value
    
        else:
            return val == self.value


def partition(df, question):
        true_rows, false_rows = [],[]
        for row in df:
            if question.match(row):
                true_rows.append(row)
            else:
                false_rows.append(row)
        return true_rows, false_rows
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-386e8df97e85> in <module>
----> 2 true_rows, false_rows = partition(training_data, Question(0,1))
      3 true_rows

<ipython-input-52-9ff7f19eff20> in partition(df, question)
     20         true_rows, false_rows = [],[]
     21         for row in df:
---> 22             if question.match(row):
     23                 true_rows.append(row)
     24             else:

<ipython-input-12-928374ee6f4e> in match(self, example)
     14         #feature value in the question
     15 
---> 16         val = example[self.column]
     17         if is_numeric(val):
     18             return val >= self.value

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm trying to adapt this code from a Decision Tree so that it can be applied to a pandas dataframe instead of a list, I get the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable", how do I return a count or a list of rows in the dataframe that were true or false without getting the error, I know that I'm not iterating through the dataframe properly, all help is really appreciated!

Comment: You are using an iterator where there are df methods for making conditional selections just like you want.

Comment: to make it easier, include the full trace of the error and provide a [mcve], but it seems like `example[self.column]` is the issue. When you do `for row in df` you're not getting rows, you're getting indexes I believe. So `example` is an int, and you can't use index notation (the brackets) on an int.  Again, we're only expeculating since we don't have a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely in your iterator. `for row in df` does not iterate over the rows. It is equivalent to `for column_name in df.columns`. What you probably want is the following to get all the rows.

```
for loc, row in df.iterrows():
   ...
```

That said, you will get better performance if you instead create a column for this.

```
def partition(df, question_column, true_value):
    view_of_values = df[question_column]
    example = view_of_values[0]
    if is_numeric(example):
        is_true = view_of_values >= true_value
    else:
        is_true = view_of_values == true_value
    # is_true is a column of True, False values for each
    # you could store this df['question_A_is_true'] = is_true
    # for partitioning later.
    return is_true


df['question_A_is_true'] = partition(df, 'question_A', 'the_truth_is_out_there')
```

Then you can do things like `df.query('question_A_is_true')` or  `df.loc[df['question_A_is_true]]` to get just the true rows. And if you have multiple questions you can then do combinations of them that are very fast because they use numpy under the hood.

```
df.loc[
   (df['question_A_is_true'])
   or (df['question_B_is_true'] and not df['question_C_is_true'])
]
```